# Find the most frequently word using hashmaps c++

Tags: c++, hashmap, find-occurrences

I need to find the most frequently occurring word and return that value. I must use hash maps and the fuction would take a file name. This is what I've done so far but im very confused.

```
  int most_frequent_word(string filename)
  {
  string words;
  ifstream in(filename.c_str());
  unordered_map<string, int> word_map;
  while(in >> words)
  {

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        word_map[words[i]]++;
    }
   }
  return words;
  }
```

any help would be appreciated it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code that might cause it to work not as expected.

First is for `i` loop. Why would you need taht loop at all? Leave it like this, you need to count words.

```
while(in >> words)
{
    word_map[words]++;
}
```

Rename `words` to `word`, actually you are reading one word here `in >> words`.

The third is return statement. You cannot return `string` when it is declared that function returns `int`.

However there is nothing to return yet, because so far we only know the number each word occurred. Run a loop to find max value.

```
int result = 0;
for(unordered_map<string, int>::iterator it = word_map.begin(); it != word_map.end(); it++)
    result = max(result, it->second);
return result;
```

Here `word_map` consists of pairs of a word and its number of occurrences. We need to iterate over all of these pairs looking for max occurrences. To do this we use iterator `it`.

Comment: Can you explain me that for please? I really dont understand it.

Comment: @Jean Alexander, are you talking about finding the max value?

Comment: Yes I am xD I dont understand that map.get or map.end what's that?

Comment: @Jean Alexander, there are iterators which allow you to iterate over items in data structure. It looks very similar to regular for loop iterating with variable `i`. However to access the value iterator is pointing to we should dereference it using either `->` or `*` operators. In this case iterator points to a `pair<string, int>`, we are interested in the second part. Hence `it->second` which is current word counter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also confused!

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    word_map[words[i]]++;
}
```

What are you doing here? Where does the 100 come from? Why do you care for single letters of your words (which is what `words[i]` gets you)?

If I understand your task correctly, wouldn't it suffice to

```
++word_map[words];
```

instead?

Also why do you return `words`? It's a string, and your function should return and int. Instead find the largest value in your map and you're done.

Comment: Sorry I'm very confused with this hash maps I just wrote 100 as a random value xD

Comment: @JeanAlexander that's rarely a successful strategy when programming :-P